# How to setup kafka and zookeeper on your local machine?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have installed kafka and zookeeper on my local C:\ drive folder now i am trying to run the zookeeper and kafka server so i can create topics but its throwing below error, any idea what is going wrong here ?

kafka comand Line:

```
C:\kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.pro
erties
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\server\jvm
dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

zookeeper.config

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=\zookeeper-3.4.8
clientPort=2181
```

Comment: I never used Kafka on Windows. However, the file `server.pro
erties` you are using contains lines starting with '#' -- on Linux, this are comments. It seems that Windows cannot deal with those comment lines. Try to delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up ZOOKEEPER_HOME in system variable ?
Please follow this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJKesEpO6ok

Comment: Thanks it helps to understand kafka setup.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version kafka_2.12-3.1.0 (2022) after unzipping and setting the properties and logs. keep the Kafka folder on the C drive and always run the command prompt with 'run as administrator'.
You can configure zookeeper with below commands
The .bat file is for windows

Terminal 1 zookeeper

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties

Terminal 2 Server

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\server.properties

Terminal 3 Creating a Topic

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --topic tutorialGB
> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

> `Created topic tutorialGB.`

To checklist of topic created

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server
> localhost:9092
>
> `tutorialGB`